# create a form that returns multiple objects

Tags: php, html

```
<?php foreach ($DATA['evidencija'] as $evidencija): ?>
                        <?php if ($evidencija->zaposleni_id == $zaposleni->zaposleni_id) { ?>
                            <?php if ($evidencija->evidencija == 'nema unosa') {?>
                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="dan[]" id="id" required class="input-field" value="<?php echo $evidencija->zaposleni_id; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="dan[]" id="date" required class="input-field" value="<?php echo $evidencija->date; ?>" >
                                        <input type="text" name="dan[]" id="evid" required class="input-field" pattern="[A-z 0-9\-]+" value="8">
                                </td>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <td style="text-align:center; color:blue; font-size:30px"><?php  echo ($evidencija->evidencija); ?></td> 
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

this HTML form code in my $_POST returns:

```
Array
(
    [dan] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2021-08-01
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2021-08-02
            [5] => 8
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2021-08-03
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 2
            [10] => 2021-08-04
            [11] => 8
            [12] => 2
            [13] => 2021-08-05
            [14] => 8
            [15] => 2
            [16] => 2021-08-06
            [17] => 8
            [18] => 2
            [19] => 2021-08-07
            [20] => 8
      )
)
```

what I want my post to return is simply a list of objects that each contain these 3 elements:
something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-01
            [evid] => 8
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-02
            [evid] => 8
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-03
            [evid] => 8
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-04
            [evid] => 8
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-05
            [evid] => 8
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-06
            [evid] => 8
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2021-08-07
            [evid] => 8
        )
```

it is important to me because each object is later sent to my database as such. it will be much harder to split this array and send it like so. This is the best explanation i can come up with. Any info on how to make a form return an object?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using "dan[]" as the input name for 'id', 'date' and 'avid' you can group these input values like so:

```
dan[0][id]
dan[0][date]
dan[0][evid]

dan[1][id]
dan[1][date]
dan[1][evid]
```

If I fill in your code, it looks something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($DATA['evidencija'] as $k=>$evidencija): ?>
    ....
    <input type="hidden" name="dan[<?php echo $k; ?>][id]" id="id"...
    <input type="hidden" name="dan[<?php echo $k; ?>][date]" id="date" ...
    <input type="text" name="dan[<?php echo $k; ?>][evid]" id="evid"
```

This will result in an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [dan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                     [id] => 1
                     [date] => xxx
                     [evid] => xxx
                 )
         )
)
```